# Num Lock button press is not working using keyboard module in python3

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard, keypress, pyautogui

I am simulating the button press using keyboard module.
I have following code:

```
keyboard.press('num lock')# switching on the num lock key
##do some operation##
keyboard.press('num lock')# num lock key is still On
```

On second statement num lock key is not pressed down.
Please help me to get it resolved.

I have tried with pyautogui,still its not resolved.

```
pyautogui.press("num lock")
```

Thanks
Simun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you need to pass is `'numlock'`, not `'num lock'`:

```
>>> pyautogui.press("numlock")
```